# Update TextEditingController.text with other TextFields TextEditingController.text values + extra String

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have a name & last name `TextFormField` in my App

[image: ScreenShot App]

I'd like the disabled e-mail field to auto-complete with the value written inside `name field` and `last name field` + the `company domain` : `@company.com`

```
  TextEditingController emailTextController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameTextController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lastNameTextController = TextEditingController();
```

- if I init `emailTextController` to be equal to `nameTextController` it works, both value change

```
 @override
  onInit() async {
emailTextController = emailNameTextController;
    super.onInit();
  }
```

but what I'd like would be for emailTextController.text to have also `@company.com` at the end

```
  @override
  onInit() async {
    emailTextController.text = emailNameTextController.text + '@company.com';
    super.onInit();
  }
```

but value of `email field` doesn't update with value from nameField

[image: Second ScreenShot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onSubmited` or `onChanged` on the `lastName textfield`

```
TextField(
  controller: lastNameTextController ,
  onSubmitted: (text) {
  emailTextController.text = nameTextController.text + lastNameTextController.text + '@company.com';
  },
//OR us this
  onChanged(){
 emailTextController.text = nameTextController.text + lastNameTextController.text + '@company.com';
},
 
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
)
```

Comment: thank you I ended up using  `nameTextController.addListener` in Init